# Typescript conditional type missing properties

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I can't wrap my head around why the following TypeScript code fails while seemingly everything should be ok:

```js
interface Base { basic: boolean };
interface Super { basic: boolean; extra: boolean };

type Options<T> = T extends Super ? { isSuper: boolean } : { notSuper: boolean }

const baseOptions: Options<{ basic: boolean }> = { notSuper: true };                 // ok
const superOptions: Options<{ basic: boolean; extra: boolean }> = { isSuper: true }; // ok

type MakeOptions = <T>() => Options<T>

function withOptions <T>(makeOptions: MakeOptions): void {
  const options = makeOptions<T>();

  console.log(options.notSuper); // Error: Property 'notSuper' does not exist on type 'Options<T>'.(2339)
  console.log(options.isSuper);  // Error: Property 'isSuper' does not exist on type 'Options<T>'.(2339)
}
```

I expect `options.isSuper` to be `undefined | { isSuper: boolean }` and `options.notSuper` to be `undefined | { notSuper: boolean }`

Instead Typescript removes these properties alltogether.

Problem is solved when changing to

```
type Options<T> = T extends Super ? { isSuper: boolean; notSuper?: undefined } : { notSuper: boolean; isSuper?: undefined }
```

But it seems unnecessary.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN7IEabAIBc+A9mQDYRwjIC+A3ALABQoksiKAygK4AHaMlwEMRUngrVajZBAAeYKHEnSadJmzZgAnkOQB5AWGBkQGADwAVAHzIAvMmvylEEABMMyfkKjIAfhFkYAxfaDUqDQZkUlwQMjBwqEiZTW1WBHMMMHxMCGNTbNJCswtLUUIScijaBnsneMTk0mU+FCZkLu6e3q6Aen7kMgBrNiyLXIxBaFLioxMyq0rxaqlakDlFZVUatPrHYNCW5DaOuUHhsdYdfRQAWTgRgsXsw5tbAAoASkd7OfKdgyMD4IAQRToAHdgGAABYA7wfT4AWyeLwhGFIj2eCO+pAAbmRgB4RGwuhMcsNXhZDqicdSrHYfiwbqxydkogA6ShkADmnzIDM5CSSMyg3wuQwAolAoGQUsgAApyvx6ZAAchFyXVyA8ZAg3hFrlCuXMpzuGoRH3VnM+ACYAMwOgCc3zJyApXJ5-MFGM5xzFEoG0tl8tIysF0DV6oDfh1eoNyCNihNwzoegM6qtdht9qdrrY9CAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Options<T>` as you want it to return an object with the parameter `isSuper` or `notSuper` I added in an interface for both of them.

```
interface IisSuper { isSuper: boolean }
interface InotSuper { notSuper: boolean }
```

In `Options<T>`as it can either be one of the aforementioned interfaces I created a union type for it called `TSuper`.

```
type Options<T> = T extends Super ? IisSuper : InotSuper
type TSuper = IisSuper | InotSuper
```

In the function `withOptions<T>` I used the `as` keyword, which is a Type Assertion which tells the compiler to consider the object as another type than the type the compiler infers the object to be. In this case it is the union of both `IisSuper` and `InotSuper` which `Options<T>` can exist as.

As Typescript cannot guarantee the type of `options` at runtime as you want to access either `notSuper` or `isSuper` so you have to narrow down the scope using the `in` keyword for `options` to access the parameter in the type you want.

```
function withOptions <T>(makeOptions: MakeOptions): void {
  const options = makeOptions<T>() as TSuper;
  if('notSuper' in options){
    console.log(options.notSuper);
  }
  else if('isSuper' in options){
    console.log(options.isSuper);
  } 
}
```

**Final code:**

```
interface Base { basic: boolean };
interface Super { basic: boolean; extra: boolean };
interface IisSuper { isSuper: boolean }
interface InotSuper { notSuper: boolean }

type Options<T> = T extends Super ? IisSuper : InotSuper
type MakeOptions = <T>() => Options<T>
type TSuper = IisSuper | InotSuper

const baseOptions: Options<{ basic: boolean }> = { notSuper: true };                 
const superOptions: Options<{ basic: boolean; extra: boolean }> = { isSuper: true }; 

function withOptions <T>(makeOptions: MakeOptions): void {
  const options = makeOptions<T>() as TSuper;
  if('notSuper' in options){
    console.log(options.notSuper);
  }
  else if('isSuper' in options){
    console.log(options.isSuper);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you have definitely refactored it to make it more easy to reason about :)